# Request parameter in Lambda python

Tags: python, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to create Lambda using python but not able to retrieve requestparameter or headerParameter from python code. I have enabled Integration proxy in gateway.

I have used below sample code but getting error always.

```
    import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    number1 = event['Number1']
    number2 = event['Number2']
    sum = number1 + number2
    #querystring= event["queryStringParameters"]['test']
    #querystring=event['params']['querystring']['test']
    querystring=event['pathParameters']['test']
    #querystring=context["test"]
    #querystring=context["httpMethod"]
    Body = {
        "response":{
           "resultStatus": "SUCCESS",
           "results":{
               "Number1": number1,
               "Number2": number2,
               "Sum": sum,
               "querystring": querystring
           }
        }
    }
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': Body
    }
```

Getting error as

```
{
   "errorMessage": "'pathParameters'",
   "errorType": "KeyError",
   "stackTrace": ["  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 10, in lambda_handler\n    querystring=event['pathParameters']['test']\n"]
}
```

Can anyone please help on this.

Thanks!

Comment: it clearly states  keyerror, print the event and see what keys does the event shows up.

Comment: Hi @Usman , Can you please help in printing or how to solve this if you have faces similar issue earlier..

Comment: ` def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement print(event)
    number1 = event['Number1']
    number2 = event['Number2']
    sum = number1 + number2
   
   
` Add the print of event to see what exactly it contains.